# Why is my microphone crackly on Raspberry Pi OS and not Windows

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, speech-recognition, microphone, text-to-speech

I recently bought a **usb** microphone (omnidirectional) from amazon (branded 'italk-02') for use with speech recognition. When used on Windows the sound is clear and can be used with Cortana and voice search. However, on my raspberry pi (4) the sound is very crackly (I tested it with `arecord` and `aplay`), meaning speech recognition is impossible with it. I have tried Mozilla Deepspeech, PocketSphinx and the python library 'speechrecognition' all of these worked one time in ten, and only with simple words like 'and' or 'hello'. The crackle coming from the microphones is not so serious that I can't understand what is being recorded, but is very noticeable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not make aware on the original question that this is a usb microphone. I have now edited the question.

Comment: I guess that's implicit since there is no audio input otherwise.  It does make this a bit stranger, but if it's crackly to the point of being *humanly unrecognizable* w/ arecord and aplay, it is still not something that software is going to fix.  It's either the stick or the Pi or something weird about the combination.  I don't recall seeing this issue here before, so if you have another (different make, model) stick you can try and if it has the same problems, something bad is going on with the pi.